# Неисправность программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть класс "Воин". От него создаются два экземпляра-юнита. Каждому устанавливается здоровье в 100 очков. В случайном порядке они бьют друг друга. Тот, кто бьет, здоровья не теряет. У того, кого бьют, оно уменьшается на 20 очков от одного удара. После каждого удара надо выводить сообщение, какой юнит атаковал, и сколько у противника осталось здоровья. Как только у кого-то заканчивается ресурс здоровья, программа завершается сообщением о том, кто одержал победу.

Программа не позволяет каждому воину бить поочереди, если я нажал "кнопку" 1-ый воин бьет, пока не победит. Где ошибка?

```
import random


class Warrior:
  def __init__(self,health):
    self.health = health

  def hit(self,target,target1):
    while target.health > 0:
      target.health -= 20
      if target1 == warrior1:
        target1 = "Warrior1"
      if target1 == warrior2:
        target1 = "Warrior2"
      print(target1, " has attacked")
      print(target.health, " left")
    if target.health == 0:
      print(target1, " has won")  


warrior1 = Warrior(100)   
warrior2 = Warrior(100)


q = int(input("Enter 1 to let some warrior attack. Enter 2 to stop program:"))

while q != 2:
  if q == 1:
    j = random.randint(1,3)
    if j % 2 == 0:
      warrior1.hit(warrior2,warrior1)
      q = int(input("Enter 1 to let some warrior attack:"))
    else:  
      warrior2.hit(warrior1,warrior2)
      q = int(input("Enter 1 to let some warrior attack:"))
  else:
    print("Wrong input.")
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логично же, бить пока уровень здоровья не опустится до нуля или меньше:

```
while target.health > 0:
    target.health -= 20
```

Замените `while` на `if` и ошибка должна уйти

```
class Warrior:
  def __init__(self,health):
    self.health = health

  def hit(self,target,target1):
    if target.health > 0:
      target.health -= 20
      if target1 == warrior1:
        target1 = "Warrior1"
      if target1 == warrior2:
        target1 = "Warrior2"
      print(target1, " has attacked")
      print(target.health, " left")
    if target.health == 0:
      print(target1, " has won")
```